# Windows 7 Task Scheduler doesn't list my custom task(s)

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I created a custom task from another application (Peachtree), but it never showed up in the Active Tasks list. So, I created it manually from within the Task Scheduler, but the task still hasn't appeared.

I'm afraid I now have two tasks that do the same thing, but I can't change them in any way. What can I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Task Scheduler**

I had the same problem, and my custom tasks only showed up if I navigated to Task Scheduler via the method above. If I did *Start > Right-click on Computer > Manage > Task Scheduler* then they would not show up.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I have the same problem like David, but your way didn't solve it ):

Comment: only works when clicking library node

Comment: I thought this is my problem too until found out right clicking on the 'Task Scheduler Library' list and choosing 'Refresh' manually after creating the task solves it.

Comment: Using windows 8, have the same issue, still nothing. Yet the other answer fixed it

Answer (score 140):

In the Task Scheduler if the line "Task Scheduler (Local)" is selected, you won't see your custom tasks. Select "Task Scheduler Library" (not the plus sign, the words themselves) and you will see your custom tasks.

[image: Vista Task Scheduler]

Comment: I just wanted to add that, even after you click the "Task Scheduler Library" you won't see your new tasks. You need to explicitly refresh this list. It took me a while to figure this out because I couldn't see any of my new tasks even after changing pages back and forth. I wrongly assumed that changing pages would refresh the list. Hit F5 or right click > Refresh.

Comment: actually I had to combine both good answers above to succeed

Comment: also be sure to refresh =D

Answer (score 1):

Your task should sit on a folder which you had clicked on the folder under Task Scheduler Library before you click on Create Task... to create your task.
Sometime you didn't know which folder you clicked before you created your task, then you have to go through all folders to find the task.