# How to stop my PC from shutting down automatically at 6 A.M in morning?

Tags: windows-7

Few months back i scheduled shutdown task at 6 A.M in morning using windows 7 task scheduler, now i don't know how to stop that from re-occurring.
     I can't find it in the task scheduler.Is there any way to find the shutdown task and delete it or disable it.

Comment: Will this one help you?: http://superuser.com/questions/228235/windows-7-task-scheduler-doesnt-list-my-custom-tasks

Comment: Thanks, It helps. why didn't i check that (:-.Top hit is the answer